# Screencapture sandbox error on Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox, macos-sierra

Calling /usr/sbin/screencapture from a sandboxed app (using NSTask) on macOS Sierra (beta 1 or 2) is generating a sandbox violation error and I get an error as result.

```
com.apple.sandbox.reporting Category: violation
screencapture(3428) deny mach-register com.apple.screencapture.interactive
Violation:       deny mach-register com.apple.screencapture.interactive
Process:         screencapture [3428]
Path:            /usr/sbin/screencapture
Load Address:    0x10154a000
Identifier:      screencapture
```

Adding com.apple.security.temporary-exception.match-lookup.global-name on Entitlements didn't help.

On versions before Sierra this was working without any problems. There are changes regarding sandox in 10.12?

Comment: Adding this entitlement to app’s .plist is fixing the issue, but Apple doesn't allow us to upload builds on iTunes Connect with it: <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-register.global-name</key>
<string>com.apple.screencapture.interactive</string> to the